# Difference between sucblass < superclass and subclass < module::superclass in ruby

Tags: ruby

A superclass is defined in a module, saved as an .rb file and brought into runtime memory using the "require" option in Ruby. Now in case I want to create a subclass for that superclass, both the `subclass < superclass` and `subclass < module::superclass` notations work. Is there any difference between using these?

The .rb file:

```
module Maths
    class Multiply
        def square (n)
            n*n
        end
    end
end

require "C:/InstantRails/SamplScripts/Maths"
class Cube < Multiply
    def cubert (n)
        n*n*n
    end
end

class Quad < Maths::Multiply
    def quadrt (n)
        n*n*n*n
    end
end
```

Both work fine. No error or warnings thrown.

Comment: It actually raises `uninitialized constant Multiply (NameError)` on `class Cube < Multiply` this line.

Comment: It shouldn't work unless `Cube` is defined inside the module `Maths`.

Comment: Actually in previous tries, i didn't open new irb sessions every time.. So it might have worked because i tried the same super class 'Maths' already in same session.. It throws error in fresh irb session, thanks for clarification.